# The mathematical meta magician

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

The famulus of a mathematical meta magician puts infinitely many cards 
into a top hat.
Each of these cards carries a non-negative integer.
The top hat contains

- exactly $n$ cards showing the integer $0$,
- exactly $n$ cards showing the integer $1$,
- exactly $n$ cards showing the integer $2$,
- exactly $n$ cards showing the integer $3$,
- exactly $n$ cards showing the integer $4$,
- and so on.

Then the mathematical meta magician starts removing cards from the top hat.

- In the $1$st step, the magician takes ten cards with total value $1$.
- in the $2$nd step, the magician takes ten cards with total value $2$,
- in the $3$rd step, the magician takes ten cards with total value $3$,
- in the $4$th step, the magician takes ten cards with total value $4$,
- in the $5$th step, the magician takes ten cards with total value $5$,
- and so on,
- in the $k$th step, the magician takes ten cards with total value $k$,
- and so on.

> **Question:** What is the smallest possible integer $n$, for which 
>   the mathematical meta magician can make an infinite number of such 
>   steps (without ever getting stuck)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following shows the optimal way to pull numbers out the hat, showing every $1$ that is used. Below, $n$ is $100$. This can obviously be continued forever.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

All that remains to be shown is that there is no way to do this with only $99$ copies of each card. Notice that on the $k^{th}$ day, the magician has drawn $10k$ cards with average value $\frac{k+1}{20}$. However, we can also bound the average of the first $10k$ cards, and if this is greater than $\frac{k+1}{20}$, the magician can't do their trick. In particular consider the $cn^{th}$ step. The lowest $10cn$ cards will be numbered from $0$ to $10c-1$, each having a set of $n$ cards. Thus, they average to $\frac{10c}2=5c$. This yields that we must have
$$\frac{cn+1}{20}\geq 5c$$
$$cn+1 \geq 100 c$$
meaning $n\geq 100$.